# Overwriting content of PHP file

Tags: php

I want to ovewrite some labeled data in PHP Config file which looks like this:

```
define("__dbhost__",                    '{DB_HOST}');
define("__dbname__",                    '{DB_NAME}');
define("__dbuser__",                    '{DB_USER}');
define("__dbpass__",                    '{DB_PASS}');
define("__dbport__",                    '{DB_PORT}');
```

So the file is really simple.

The way i'm trying to replace data is by:

```
$searchF  = array('{DB_HOST}','{DB_NAME}','{DB_USER}','{DB_PASS}', '{DB_PORT}');
$replaceW = array('a','c','d','b','a');

$fname = "../app/config/database.php";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
$content = str_replace($searchF, $replaceW, $content);

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
```

But once finished and after I open the file I get

```
Resource id #16
```

Inside of it.

What's going on and why typical str_replace won't work for this case?

Comment: you have written the file handle

Comment: the problem is not with `str_replace`. Please echo `$content` on each step before you write it into the file

Comment: What you're trying to do is very odd. Yes there's a one liner to do this using `file_put_contents($fname,str_replace(..., ..., file_get_contents($fname)))` but the real question is why are you doing this?

Comment: close the file handle before opening it for writing

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the entire file into a string:

```
$searchF  = array('{DB_HOST}','{DB_NAME}','{DB_USER}','{DB_PASS}', '{DB_PORT}');
$replaceW = array('a','c','d','b','a');

$fname = "../app/config/database.php";
$content = file_get_contents($fname);
$content = str_replace($searchF, $replaceW, $content);
file_put_contents($fname, $content);
```

- Read file into string
- Replace on that string
- Write string to file